# sub-queries inside check constraint

Tags: sql, check-constraints

If I have a person table, with 2 fields (name and address).

```
create table PERSON  (
NAME                 VARCHAR2(50),
ADDRESS              VARCHAR2(100)  
);
```

How do I ensure that all people with the same address have different names.

I was trying to use `CHECK` constraint, there are some examples on the web that use sub-queries inside the create table statement, but I got an SQL Error:

> ORA-02251: subquery not allowed here

Any helps would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: A unique index on name, address should do. So you can't insert the same combination of name/address twice. Which on the other hand means that all names for the same address have to be different.

Answer (score 1):

You can not leave the row in check constraint. You can use triggers for this purpose.

Comment: Me thinks that a unique constraint (as per @a_horse_with_no_name's comment) is cleaner than a kludge of triggers.